# django-oauth-toolkit : Customize authenticate response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-oauth, django-oauth-toolkit

I am new to Django OAuth Toolkit. I want to customize the authenticate response.

My authenticate url configuration on django application is :

```
url('authenticate/',
    include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider'))
```

https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Now, when i launch this command :

```
curl -X POST -d 'grant_type=password&username=$username&password=$password'
 -u "$client_id:$client_secret" http://127.0.0.1:8000/authenticate/token/
```

I get this response :

```
{
   "access_token": "ATiM10L0LNaldJPk12drXCjbhoeDR8",
   "expires_in": 36000,
   "refresh_token": "II4UBhXhpVDEKWmsUQxDzkj3OMjW1p",
   "scope": "read groups write",
   "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

And would like this response :

```
{
   "access_token": "ATiM10L0LNaldJPk12drXCjbhoeDR8",
   "expires_in": 36000,
   "refresh_token": "II4UBhXhpVDEKWmsUQxDzkj3OMjW1p",
   "scope": "read groups write",
   "token_type": "Bearer",
   "member": {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "username",
      "email": "email@gmail.com",
      ....
   }
}
```

I just want to override this response for add information of authenticated user. 
I have read the documentation of django-oauth-toolkit. And i didn't find a solution to my problem...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was able to make this change by overwriting the TokenView class
**in your views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from oauth2_provider.views.base import TokenView
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.debug import sensitive_post_parameters
from oauth2_provider.models import get_access_token_model, get_application_model
from oauth2_provider.signals import app_authorized
import json


class CustomTokenView(TokenView):
    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters("password"))
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        url, headers, body, status = self.create_token_response(request)
        if status == 200:
            body = json.loads(body)
            access_token = body.get("access_token")
            if access_token is not None:
                token = get_access_token_model().objects.get(
                    token=access_token)
                app_authorized.send(
                    sender=self, request=request,
                    token=token)
                body['member'] = {
                    'id': token.user.id, 
                    'username': token.user.username, 
                    'email': token.user.email
                }
                body = json.dumps(body) 
        response = HttpResponse(content=body, status=status)
        for k, v in headers.items():
            response[k] = v
        return response
```

In **urls.py**, just overwrite the token url by pointing to the custom view. This import should come before the include of the django-oauth-toolkit

```
url(r"authenticate/token/$", CustomTokenView.as_view(), name="token"),
url('authenticate/',
    include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider'))
```

The return will now contain the member data

```
  {
    "access_token": "YtiH9FGwAf7Cb814EjTKbv3FCpLtag", 
    "expires_in": 36000, 
    "token_type": "Bearer", 
    "scope": "read write groups", 
    "refresh_token": "99TyWmCwELrJvymT8m6Z9EPxGr3PJi", 
    "member": {
        "id": 1, 
        "username": "admin", 
        "email": "admin@admin.com"
     }
  }
```

Comment: This is brillant!

Comment: ```from oauth2_provider.signals import app_authorized```

Comment: Documents : https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html

Comment: Looks good. But since most of this code is already in the `TokenView`, wouldn't just calling `response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)` and updating the `response` with member work?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how many people use **drf_social_oauth2** but you can also do the same with that. Here is my solution overwriting the [drf-social-oauth2 Token View](https://github.com/wagnerdelima/drf-social-oauth2/blob/d674cccdd266d83e1bfba61a6a0a662afacc026b/drf_social_oauth2/views.py#L40-L68)

```
url(r"authenticate/token/$", CustomTokenView.as_view(), name="token"),
```

**views.py**

```
import json
from rest_framework.response import Response
from drf_social_oauth2.views import TokenView
from oauth2_provider.models import get_access_token_model, get_application_model
from oauth2_provider.signals import app_authorized


class CustomTokenView(TokenView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         mutable_data = request.data.copy()
          request._request.POST = request._request.POST.copy()
           for key, value in mutable_data.items():
                request._request.POST[key] = value
            url, headers, body, status = self.create_token_response(
                request._request)
            if status == 200:
                body = json.loads(body)
                access_token = body.get("access_token")
                if access_token is not None:
                    token = get_access_token_model().objects.get(
                        token=access_token)
                    app_authorized.send(
                        sender=self, request=request,
                        token=token)
                    body['member'] = {
                        'id': token.user.id,
                        'username': token.user.username,
                        'email': token.user.email
                    }
                    body = json.dumps(body)
            response = Response(data=json.loads(body), status=status)

            for k, v in headers.items():
                response[k] = v
            return response
```

Comment: Solved this thanks to the Top Answer Here

Answer (score 0):

This too can work

```
import json

from oauth2_provider.models import get_access_token_model
from oauth2_provider.views import TokenView as OAuth2TokenView


class TokenView(OAuth2TokenView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        body = json.loads(response.content)
        access_token = body.get("access_token")
        token = get_access_token_model().objects.get(token=access_token)
        body["member"] = {
            "id": token.user.id,
            "email": token.user.email,
            "username": token.user.username,
        }
        response.content = json.dumps(body)
        return response
```

and in `urls.py` add

```
    path("o/token/", TokenView.as_view(), name="token"),
    path("o/", include("oauth2_provider.urls", namespace="oauth2_provider")),
```