# Customize Django rest framework authentication response {"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-oauth

I am using django 2.1 and python 3.6 and django rest framework 3.8.2 ... I am trying to find a way to customize the json response when authentication failed.

I am using a third party package [Django OAuth Toolkit](https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit)

The only way I could think of is writing a custom authentication class

```
{ "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." }
```

```
{ "Failure": "Authentication credentials were not provided. xyz etc" }
```

My attempt at overwriting the BaseAuthorizationView

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from oauth2_provider.views.base import TokenView, BaseAuthorizationView
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.debug import sensitive_post_parameters
from oauth2_provider.models import get_access_token_model, get_application_model


class CustomAuthorizationView(BaseAuthorizationView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.oauth2_data = {}
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def error_response(self, error, application, **kwargs):
        """
        Handle errors either by redirecting to redirect_uri with a json in the body containing
        error details or providing an error response
        """
        redirect, error_response = super().error_response(error, **kwargs)

        if redirect:
            return self.redirect(error_response["url"], application)

        status = error_response["error"].status_code
        return self.render_to_response("hello", status=status)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
...
    url(r"o/authorize/", appointmentViews.CustomAuthorizationView, name="authorize"),
    path('o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
...
```

Please let me know if I could provide more information! Thank you in advance.

Comment: As you mentioned, you can write custom authentication classes. Did you try that? Is there any problem with that?

Comment: I tried overwriting (BaseAuthorizationView)[https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/views/base.py]  similar to the solution (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370004/django-oauth-toolkit-customize-authenticate-response] but had no luck

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my problem with django rest, custom exception handling
[link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)

views.py

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler


def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if response is not None:
        response.data['status_code'] = response.status_code

    return response
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'project.apps.utils.exception.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

where project (folder) > apps (folder) > utils (folder) > exception.py > custom...

response:

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided.",
    "status_code": 401
}
```